# Where does JTAGSEL connect to on a JTAG header?

Tags: jtag

I'm busy working on a PCB design for an Atmel SAM3S ARM chip. The following image is a screenshot of the JTAG 20 pin header schematic:

[image]

On the CPU, there's a pin for JTAGSEL, and looking through the [1000 page datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc6500.pdf), I'm not entirely sure where this connects to on the JTAG header?

Am I completely mistaken, is this a signal that gets pulled high/low to select between JTAG/SWD?

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JTAGSEL is not a pin the JTAG box uses, because it fundamentally changes what the JTAG box sees on the interface. There's no practical way to switch between the two without cycling power.

The JTAG interface can work with the ARM in two ways:

1. As a standard JTAG debugging port. The ARM runs and is controlled by the internal debugger circuits, allowing things like starting and stopping execution, setting breakpoints, reading internal memory, etc. This is the mode debugger (e.g. gdb) users are familiar with, and most likely what you want.
2. As a boundary scan interface. This pretty much shuts down the ARM's internal functions and lets the JTAG interface to directly control the I/O pins. This is used to drive test vectors from the ARM chip onto the board to test the rest of the board, is intended for automated test fixtures in production, and is rarely used outside production test.

When in doubt, you want option 1.

SWD is "serial wire debug", which is an alternate debugging method similar to option 1 above, just not using the exact JTAG protocol.

(I had to research this for our SAM3U boards.)

Comment: The normal ARM debug mode includes the boundary scan functionality, as well as a special shortened boundary scan chain that covers just the data bus(es) and a few control signals.

Comment: In the datasheets I've read (mostly related to SAMA5D2x boards), SWD usually stands for "serial wire debug", although it means the same thing.

Comment: That’s the correct name. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 4):

You can just leave it unconnected.

> The pin JTAGSEL is used to select the JTAG boundary scan when asserted
>   at a high level. The pin JTAGSEL integrates a permanent pull-down
>   resistor of about 15 kΩ to GND, so that it can be left unconnected for
>   normal operations.

[image]